# How to pass Cwnd Class' handle to the its calling threads?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have 2 classes which are CPacketDispatcher inherited from CWnd Class and CPacketAnalyzer inhertied from CWinThread. 
CPacketDispatcher creates several CPacketAnalyzer threads and 
when the analyzer thread has done its work, 
the thread will notify its status to Dispatcher by calling SendMessage or PostMessage function. 
But to call SendMessage function in the thread, I should get the PacketDispatcher handle as far as I know. 
So I tried to hand it over when the thread resumes in dispatcher but I think it doesn't work. 
No compliation error, but CPacket Analyzer never pass the message to the dispatcher class in SendMessage function.

Please see the ommitted codes below, give me your professional help!!

**//PacketDispatcher.h**

```
class CPacketDispatcher : public CWnd
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CPacketDispatcher)

    public:
    CString                             CLASS_TAG;
    CLogger*                            wLog;

    static CPacketDispatcher*   packetDispatcher;
    static CMutex                       m_Mutex;

private:
    int*                        m_threadId;    
    int*                        m_threadState; 

    int                     m_taskThreadId; 
    CPacketAnalyzerThread*              m_packetAnalyzerThread[MAX_THREAD_COUNT]; 

public:
    CPacketDispatcher();
    virtual ~CPacketDispatcher();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    static CPacketDispatcher* getInstance(void);
    int run(CPacketDEF *packet);
    void initializeWorkingThread(void);
    int findIdleThread(void);
protected:
    afx_msg LRESULT OnUpdatethreadstate(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

**//PacketDispatcher.cpp**

```
int CPacketDispatcher::run(CPacketDEF *packet)
{

    m_taskThreadId=findIdleThread();
    m_packetAnalyzerThread[m_taskThreadId]->m_pRcvPacket = packet;
    m_packetAnalyzerThread[m_taskThreadId]->m_pParentHwnd = this->m_hWnd;
    m_packetAnalyzerThread[m_taskThreadId]->ResumeThread();
    wLog->setLogTextOnDlg(CLASS_TAG,FUNC_TAG,"Exit Point"); 
    return 0;
}
```

**//PacketAnalyzerThread.h**

```
class CPacketAnalyzerThread : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CPacketAnalyzerThread)

//definition
public:
    CString CLASS_TAG;
    CLogger* wLog;

    int     m_threadId;
    HWND    m_pParentHwnd;

//attribute
public:
    CPacketDEF *m_pRcvPacket;

protected:
    CPacketAnalyzerThread();           
    virtual ~CPacketAnalyzerThread();

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    virtual int Run();


    int executePacketParsing(void);
    void enqueuePacket(void);
};
```

**//PacketAnalyzerThread.cpp**

```
int CPacketAnalyzerThread::Run()
{

    while(true){    

        executePacketParsing();
        SendMessage(m_pParentHwnd,WM_UpdateThreadState,(WPARAM) this->m_threadId,(LPARAM) THREAD_IDLE);
        TRACE0("After SEND MESSAGE");   
        this->SuspendThread(); // after processing one packet, the thread will be suspended until packetDispatcher resumes the thread. 
        SendMessage(m_pParentHwnd,WM_UpdateThreadState,(WPARAM) this->m_threadId,(LPARAM) THREAD_BUSY);
    }

    return CWinThread::Run();
}
```

Comment: Can you show exactly the place, where you send the message, and where you expect to handle it.

Comment: `m_packetAnalyzerThread[m_taskThreadId]->m_pParentHwnd = this->m_hWnd;` Please use  [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), for OO's sake :). `this->` is unnecessary also. Aside from that, have you used [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) (part of Visual Studio)  to see if your `CPacketDispatcher` window is actually receiving your `WM_UpdateThreadState` message, and check if `m_pParentHwnd` is the correct handle to the window you expect?

Comment: Actually, I don't need any window for CPacketDispatcher. The reason for defining as CWnd class is just for receiving messages from the CPacketAnalyzer thread. When I made breakpoint in CPacketDispatcher for debugging, the m_hWnd vaule seems to be null. How can I implement as I intended?

Comment: "m_packetAnalyzerThread[m_taskThreadId]->m_pParentHwnd = this->m_hWnd;" in this part, CPacketDispatcher hands its handle over to the thread. "SendMessage(m_pParentHwnd,WM_UpdateThreadState,(WPARAM) this->m_threadId,(LPARAM) THREAD_BUSY);" in this part, CPacketAnalyzer thread sends message to CPacketDispatcher.

Comment: Did you ever created the CPacketDispatcher window? If m_hWnd is NULL, you might created an instance of this class but never created the window. But using SendMessage requires a created widow.

Comment: I tried to create window for it such llike,"Create(NULL,NULL,WS_CHILD,CRect(0,0,0,0),this,20000);" inserted in the first line of run(CPacketDEF *packet) function, but the result was same.

Comment: As I investigated, CPacketDispatcher class is called from CWinThread class but not Main UI thread. I think that is the reason why I cannot get window handle. Is it correct? If then, What else method can be applied to communicate between CPacketDispatcher and CPacketAnalyzer?

Comment: You must Create the CWnd so it will have a valid m_hWnd. You must also put a ON_MESSAGE macro to OnUpdatethreadstate into the message map of CPacketDispatcher.